# MySql JOINS And Count() Function: #1054 - Unknown column 'T.parent' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT A.term_id, 
       B.name, 
       counts
FROM wp_term_taxonomy A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT COUNT( C.parent ) AS counts
FROM wp_term_taxonomy C
GROUP BY C.term_id
) AS T ON A.term_id = T.parent -- This line causes error
JOIN wp_terms B ON A.term_id = B.term_id
WHERE A.taxonomy =  'product_cat'
AND A.parent =0
```

I get this error when I run this syntax:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'T.parent' in 'on clause'

How do I properly reference my sub-query select statement with ON?

Answer (score 3):

You can't join a table using a on clause for a column that not exist (in you case that you don't select in the dinamically generated  table T)

You should add a parent column in t table eg:

```
SELECT A.term_id, B.name, counts
FROM wp_term_taxonomy A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT C.term_id as parent, COUNT( C.parent ) AS counts
  FROM wp_term_taxonomy C
  GROUP BY C.term_id
) AS T ON A.term_id = T.parent /* This line causes error*/
JOIN wp_terms B ON A.term_id = B.term_id
WHERE A.taxonomy =  'product_cat'
AND A.parent =0
```